# What happens to the Gaussian volume of a Borel set when it is translated?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, geometric-probability, isoperimetric-problems

Let $\gamma_n$ be the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R^n$, $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be Borel and $c \in \mathbb R^n$. Define the translate $A_c := c + A := \{c+a \mid a \in A\} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x-c \in A\}$. Assume $A$ is not too "small", e.g  $\gamma_n(A) \ge 1/2$.

## Question

- What are good lower (and perhaps upper) bounds for $\gamma_n(A_c)$ ?

## Observations

For a half-space $H = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid u^Tx \le v\}$, one has $H_c = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid u^Tx \le v + u^Tc\}$, another half-space with Gaussian volume $\gamma_n(H_c) = \Phi\left(\frac{v + u^Tc}{\|u\|}\right) = \Phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(\gamma_n(H)+\frac{u^Tc}{\|u\|}\right)$, where $\Phi$ is the 1D Gaussian CDF.

---

## Update

Let $H$ be a half-space with same Gaussian volume as $B$, i.e $\gamma_n(H)=\gamma_n(A)$.

**Question:** Under which minimal / reasonable conditions do we have $\gamma_n(A_c) \ge \gamma_n(H_c)$ ?

Comment: I have the strong feeling such questions can be answered using inequalities of Brunn-Minkowski type http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2010-362-10/S0002-9947-2010-04891-3/S0002-9947-2010-04891-3.pdf, but I don't have much experience with those tools.

Comment: One simple observation: If $A$ is a ball centered at the origin, then  $\gamma_n(A_c)<\gamma_n(A)$ for all $c\neq 0$, while for a half-space one has the sign of $\gamma_n(H_c)-\gamma_n(H)$  depending on whether $c$ points out of $H$ or into $H$ (and is zero if $c$ is parallel to \partial H$.

Comment: @RBega2 Good points. BTW, your second remark is a consequence of what I wrote down as "observations".

Comment: I've just posted an answer below, based on Neymann-Pearson theory (1933).

Answer (score 2):

Let 
\begin{equation}
 g(t):=\gamma_n(tu+c+A)=P(Z\in tu+c+A)=\int_{c+A}(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-|z+tu|^2/2}\,dz,
\end{equation}
where $t\in\mathbb R$, $u$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb R^n$, $Z$ is a standard Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb R^n$, and $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm. Then 
\begin{equation}
 g'(0)=-\int_{c+A}(2\pi)^{-n/2}z\cdot u\,e^{-|z|^2/2}\,dz
 =-p\,u\cdot E(Z|Z\in c+A), 
\end{equation}
where $p:=P(Z\in c+A)=\gamma_n(c+A)$ and $z\cdot u$ is the dot product of $z$ and $u$.

That is, the rate of change of $\gamma_n(c+A)$ with respect to $c$ in the direction of a unit vector $u$ equals the following:

> $\gamma_n(c+A)$ times the $u$-coordinate $u\cdot E(Z|Z\in c+A)$ of the center $E(Z|Z\in c+A)$ of the standard Gaussian mass over the set $c+A$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Possible simplification: Let $\mu_A \in \mathbb R^n$ be the Gaussian barycenter of $A$. Then $E(Z|Z \in c + A) = E(Z-c|Z \in A) = E(Z|Z \in A)-c = \mu_A-c$.

Comment: Thank you  for your comment. However, in general the equality $E(Z|Z\in c+A)=E(Z-c|Z\in A)$ will not hold. E.g., let $n=1$ and $A=[-1,1]$. Then for large $c>0$ we have $E(Z|Z\in c+A)\sim c$ but $E(Z-c|Z\in A)=-c$. Even the equality $E(Z|Z\in c+A)=E(Z+c|Z\in A)$ will not hold here: for these $n$ and $A$, we have  $E(Z|Z\in c+A)<c=E(Z+c|Z\in A)$ for all real $c>0$.

Comment: Oops, indeed my computations don't work. Thanks

Comment: Can the integral / differential computations in your answer be used to provide bounds (of any sort) on  $\gamma_n(c+A)$ as asked in the question, or  does your answer say the question is intricately complicated ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In view of this center-of-Gaussian-mass interpretation, much will likely depend on the choice of $A$ (and $c$, too). Even some of the considerations in my previous comment for the simplest case of $n=1$ and a convex $A$ are not quite trivial. So, I'd be greatly (and pleasantly) surprised if bounds for general $A$ are obtained.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What if $c$ is a "small" vector, compared to the volume content of $A$, $\|c\| \le \Phi^{-1}(\gamma_n(A))$, with $\gamma_n(A) \ge 1/2$ ?

Comment: I think, again in view of the highlighted center-of-Gaussian-mass interpretation, the Gaussian content of $A$ is only relevant as a kind of constant factor. I also don't think that this problem has much to do with isoperimetric problems.

Comment: I've just posted an answer below, based on Neymann-Pearson theory (1933). Lemme know what you think. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Neyman-Pearson theory helps get a nontrivial inequality.

**Notations.** For a p.s.d matrix $M$ of size $p$, consider the inner product on $\mathbb R^p$
defined by $\langle x,z \rangle_M := x^TMz$. This induces a norm defined by
$\|x\|_M:=\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle_M}$.

> **Theorem** *(Neyman-Pearson for translated multivaritate Gaussians).*
> Let $\beta \in \mathbb R$, $\delta\in \mathbb R^p$ and $A$ be a
> Borell subset of $\mathbb R^p$. Let $X \sim \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ and
> $Y:=X+\delta$. Consider the half-space
> \begin{eqnarray}
>     H=\{z \in \mathbb R^p \mid \langle\delta,z\rangle_{\Sigma^{-1}} \le \beta\}.
>  \end{eqnarray}

> - If $\mathbb P(X \in A) \ge \mathbb P(X \in H)$, then $\mathbb P(Y \in A) \ge
>       \mathbb P(Y \in H)$.

> - If $\mathbb P(X \in A) \le \mathbb P(X \in H^c)$, then $\mathbb P(Y \in A) \le
>       \mathbb P(Y \in H^c)$.

*Proof.* The log of the ratio of the densities of $Y$ and $X$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \begin{split}
    \log(f_Y(z))-\log(f_X(z)) &=
    -\frac{1}{2}(z-\delta)^T\Sigma^{-1}(z-\delta)-\frac{1}{2}z^T\Sigma^{-1}z\\
    &= \langle \delta,z \rangle_{\Sigma^{-1}}-\frac{1}{2}\|\delta\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}^2.
    \end{split}
  \end{eqnarray*}
Thus $f_Y(z) \le t f_X(z)$ iff $\langle \delta,z
  \rangle_{\Sigma^{-1}}-\frac{1}{2}\|\delta\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}^2 \le \log(t)$.
Define $t := e^{\beta-\frac{1}{2}\|\delta\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}^2}$. Then $S_t=H$,
and we can apply the Neyman-Pearson Lemma (see Appendix below) to get the claimed results. $\Box$

---

## Appendix

The following Lemma is a modern formulation of the celebrated [Neyman-Pearson Lemma](http://www.joelvelasco.net/teaching/249/Neyman%20Pearson%201933.pdf).

> **Lemma** *(Neyman-Pearson 1933).*
> Let $A$ be an event in a probability space $\mathcal Z$, and let $X$, $Y$ be random
> variables on $\mathcal Z$, with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively.
> Finally, let $t > 0$ and define
> \begin{eqnarray}
>     S_t:= \{z \in \mathcal Z \mid f_Y(z) \le tf_X(z)\}.
>   \end{eqnarray}
> We have the following:

> - If $\mathbb P(X \in A) \ge \mathbb P(X \in S_t)$, then $\mathbb P(Y \in
>       A) \ge \mathbb P(Y \in S_t)$.

> - If $\mathbb P(X \in A) \le \mathbb P(X \in S_t^c)$, then $\mathbb P(Y \in
>       A) \le \mathbb P(Y \in S_t^c)$.

*Proof.*
Suppose $\mathbb P(X \in A) \ge \mathbb P(X \in S_t)$, and let $A^c$ be the set
complement of $A$ in $\mathcal Z$. One computes
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \begin{split}
      &\mathbb P(Y \in A)-\mathbb P(Y \in S_t)=\int 1_A(z)f_Y(z)dz-\int_{S_t}f_Y(z)dz\\
      &= \int_{S_t} 1_A(z)f_Y(z)dz+\int_{S_t^c} 1_A(z)f_Y(z)dz-\left(\int_{S_t}
        1_A(z)f_Y(z)dz+\int_{S_t} 1_{A^c}(z)f_Y(z)dz  \right)\\
      &=\int_{S_t^c} 1_A(z)f_Y(z)dz-\int_{S_t} 1_{A^c}(z)f_Y(z)dz\\
      &\ge t\left(\int_{S_t^c} 1_A(z)f_X(z)dz-\int_{S_t}
        1_{A^c}(z)f_X(z)dz\right),\text{ by definition of }S_t\\
      &= t(\mathbb P(X \in A)-\mathbb P(X \in S_t)) \ge 0,\text{ by assumption}.
    \end{split}
  \end{eqnarray*}
Thus $\mathbb P(Y \in A) \ge \mathbb P(Y \in S_t)$. Similarly, one proves
the second part of the claim with "$\ge$" replaced with "$\le$". $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$

Comment: Looks like a nice idea.

Comment: I believe the statement is wrong -- specifically, both Theorem and Lemma should have a complement on the second item ($H^c$ and $S_t^c$ for the second bullet of each statement).

Comment: Yes, obviously. That's what happens when you prove one part of a result and state that "the proof of the second part is completely analogous to the first". Fixed.